# What does "Awaiting Reviewers Selection" in scholarone means

Tags: science, review-articles

I submitted a paper to a journal that used scholarone and the reviewers recommended a major revision. I addressed every single comment of reviewers and made all the suggested changes.

Now, it is in the “Awaiting Reviewers Selection” mode once again. Does anybody explain why the journal editor needs to select new reviewers at this step of the review process?

Comment: For a major revision typically the article will be sent through the review process again. Sometimes it is sent to original reviewers, sometimes new reviewers are selected, sometimes a mix. Seems like at least one new reviewer is needed.

Answer (score 0):

It may just be a glitch or they have not yet sent out your new version to the referees. I'd recommend waiting for a day or two while they send it out to the reviewers.